# How to delete tied objects in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots, qt5

There are two classes: `Widget` and `Worker`. Here is a schematic code.

```
class Widget
{
    Worker *m_worker;
    QTextEdit *m_edit;
public:

    Widget():m_edit(new QTextEdit){}

   ~Widget()
   {
       m_worker->ShouldStop = true;
       delete *m_worker;
   }

   void doWork()
   {
      m_worker = new Worker;

      if (!worker->doWork())
          m_edit->setText("failed");
   }
}

class Worker
{

    Worker() : ShouldStop(false){}

public:
    bool ShouldStop;

    bool doWork()
    {
        while(true && !ShouldStop)
        {
            QThread::sleep(1);
            QApplication::processEvents();
        }

        //consider the work undone if a stop was forced
        if (ShouldStop)
            return false;
    }
}
```

After a call to `doWork()` of the `Widget` the execution loops in the method `doWork()` of the `Worker`. A widget is then closed and its destructor is called during one of the calls to `processEvents()`. Then the execution then returns to the `doWork()` of the `Worker`.
It now checks `ShouldStop` and returns to the `doWork()` of the `Widget` and tries to add something to the `m_edit`. However the `Widget` object is already dead.

Questions:

1. How can a Worker be deleted cleanly?
2. What is the best design to avoid such an interplay?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, worker threads should just return data via the signals and slots mechanism, not directly accessing the original object. Actually creating a thread and avoiding the call to `QApplication::processEvents()` is the first way to avoid the problem.

Additionally, you should consider using a design like this when you want to start a worker in a new thread. Rather than subclassing QThread, you can just create a generic QThread and assign a QObject to it, like so:

```cpp
Worker *worker = new Worker;
QThread *workerThread = new QThread(this);

connect(workerThread, &QThread::started, worker, &Worker::doWork);
connect(workerThread, &QThread::finished, worker, &Worker::deleteLater);
worker->moveToThread(workerThread);

// Starts an event loop, and emits workerThread->started()
workerThread->start();
```

Consider restructuring your code around this pattern if you're using Qt 5.

Comment: Thanks, but what is Qt5 specific in your answer?

Comment: That works from 4.8+, I think. I just haven't tested, and I'm fairly sure my signals and slots syntax is Qt5 specific.

Answer (score 2):

@Alex answer is definitely the way to go for q2. He just forgot to mention how to proceed for the deletion (q1). Assuming `Widget` created the object `workerThread`, then this is necessary:

```
 ~Widget(){
   if(workerThread->isRunning()){
         workerThread->terminate(); <--- this line, right there
         workerThread->wait(): 
   }
 ...
 }
```

Why? Because deleting a `QThread` just delete the thread object [but doesn't stop the thread from running, and may crash the application](http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/qthread.html#dtor.QThread). Note that if you are using

`connect(workerThread, &QThread::finished, worker, &Worker::deleteLater);`

as Alex mentioned, then it is not safe to access `worker` after the call to `terminate`, because it will trigger the `finished()` signal ,execute `worker->deleteLater`, and eventually delete `worker`.

Answer (score 1):

You could have Widget use a signal to inform the owner of Widget to start up Worker for the Widget.

Owner owns both Widget and Worker. Widget tells Owner that something was triggered, and Owner is responsible for deciding that Worker's doWork() is the correct response, and for managing the lifetime of both Worker and Widget. Worker and Widget are ignorant of each other, but Owner might connect some of their signals and slots together.